# What is the location of Laravel's error logs?

Tags: laravel, logging

I'm debugging a JSON endpoint and need to view internal server errors. However, my `app/storage/logs` dir is empty and it seems there are no other directories dedicated to logs in the project. I've tried googling the subject to no avail.

How can I enable logging, if it's not already enabled and view the logs?

Comment: Can you please tell what is your current setup? SO and http server.

Comment: By default Laravel should log everything in the `storage` folder. Does your configuration have the correct permissions to store in the logs? You can check your apache logs in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` - this will tell you if you don't have the correct permissions.

Comment: which method are you using for logging? `error_log` would use the default PHP log directory and `Log::error` would use the default Laravel log directory

Comment: @ÁlvaroGuimarães I'm not sure how to do that, but everything is set to defaults

Comment: @James According to Denis Mysenko, who answered the question, the permissions are not an issue

Comment: @Edwin I'm using the `errorlog` and the logs are indeed in the default PHP logging dir! Thank you

Answer (score 121, accepted):

- Ensure debug mode is on - either add `APP_DEBUG=true` to .env file or set an environment variable
- Log files are in storage/logs folder. `laravel.log` is the default filename. If there is a permission issue with the log folder, Laravel just halts. So if your endpoint generally works - permissions are not an issue.
- In case your calls don't even reach Laravel or aren't caused by code issues - check web server's log files (check your Apache/nginx config files to see the paths).
- If you use PHP-FPM, check its log files as well (you can see the path to log file in PHP-FPM pool config).

Comment: The `laravel.log` file is absent, though the logs are present in the default PHP log dir

Comment: Either there are no exceptions/errors on Laravel side or Laravel doesn't have enough permissions to write to the log file. What do you see in HTTP client - do you see any error at all?

Comment: No, there are no displayed errors in the HTTP client. Didn't you just say, that the Laravel would just halt if there were any permission issues?

Comment: Yep, then that could be an issue. Check under what user your web process is running, ensure that this user has permissions to write to 1) storage/logs 2) storage/framework 3) bootstrap/cache folders

Answer (score 23):

You should be checking the root directory and not the app directory.

Look in `$ROOT/storage/laravel.log` not `app/storage/laravel.log`, where **root** is the top directory of the project.

Comment: I think it's *storage/logs/laravel.log* not *storage/laravel.log*, relative to the project's root directory.

Comment: where is the $root at? if I do this: ```cd /``` i see some folders but not storage, the only thing that has a storage folder is inside the app folder but same as OP, I have no ```laravel.logs``` file, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

In Laravel 6, by default the logs are in:

**storage/logs/laravel.log**

Answer (score 4):

The location of the log file can be found inside `channels` array `config/logging.php` (See below)

[image]

In case if some one is looking to write to the `single` channel,
using Laravel's Log Facade, here's how to do.

`Log::channel('single')->info('Your message');`

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that `APP_DEBUG=true` is set to on on you .env

If you want to easily check your storage log you can install:

https://github.com/rap2hpoutre/laravel-log-viewer

Answer (score 0):

You can access the location programmatically by `storage_path() . '/logs'`:

```php
$logFiles = array_filter(
    scandir(storage_path() . '/logs'), 
    fn($fn) => !str_starts_with($fn,'.') // filter everything that begins with dot
);
```