# Can't start Laravel, I get "Base table or view not found" error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-migrations

First I rolled back 2 migrations by mistake, then I ran `php artisan migrate` command and I got the following error:

`[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'exercise1.categories' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from
  categories where parent_id = 0)
  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'exercise1.categories' doesn't exist`

Then I stopped Laravel. After that when I run the `php artisan serve` command for starting Laravel I get the same error. 
Here are 2 migrations which I've rolled back:

**1.**

```
class CreateCategoriesTable extends Migration
    {

        public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('categories',function (Blueprint $table){
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('name');
                $table->text('parent_id');
                $table->timestamps();
        });
        }
        public function down()
        {
            Schema::dropIfExists('categories');
        }
    }
```

**2.**

```
class CreateArticlesTable extends Migration
    {
        public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('title')->nullable(false);
                $table->longText('article')->nullable(false);
                $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
                $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }
        public function down()
        {
            Schema::dropIfExists('articles');
        }
    }
```

Please help me to solve this frustrating problem. All answers are highly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Do `composer dumpautoload` then try to migrate again.

Comment: You usually get this error if you're trying to drop a table without `dropIfExists()` which you have or when you're referencing the `categories` table for a foreign key - which you're not doing in your showcase code. Are you maybe trying to reference `categories` table in some other migration? Maybe you tried to add foreign key to your `parent_id` (a wild guess) in some latter migration?

Comment: For debugging further check the end of the file in app/storage/logs/laravel.log - which points exactly to where the problem happens

Comment: @aynber, I've already tried that, no success. All php artisan commands give the same error.

Comment: @devk Thanks for suggestion. I don't reference <code>categories</code> table in other migrations. I didn't add foreign key to <code>parent_id</code> in latter migrations.

Comment: @devk your suggestion about checking log file helped me to find a solution for this problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: For those who end up being here because of the "migrations" table is not created automatically, this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60095493/10539212) might help.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you encounter with this problem and if it's not caused by migration files then most probably it happens because of 2 possible reasons.

1. Check **ServiceProviders**' boot function if it contains queries that are querying tables that don't exist.
2. Check if you've created **custom helper function** and autoloaded that helper function in composer.json file. If custom helper function contains queries that are querying tables that don't exist it will cause this error.

Since ServiceProviders' boot functions and autoloaded custom helper functions are loaded first when laravel is started all the `php artisan` commands will generate "Base table or view not found" error.

At this point what you  should do is comment out those queries that are querying nonexistent tables and run `php artisan serve` then run `php artisan migrate`. Then uncomment those lines, save it and everything should work fine.

As  @devk suggested it's better to check laravel log files which points exactly to where the problem happens. It led me to find a solution.
For this don't forget to [Turn on debug mode.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37535315/where-are-logs-located)

Answer (score 3):

When you've rolled back these migrations, you've deleted `categories` and `articles` tables. So just run `migrate` command again:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: I think that's where he's getting the error. "First I rolled back 2 migrations by mistake, then I ran `php artisan migrate` command and I got the following error"

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But as I noted above I've already tried that and I get the same error.

Comment: @MahammadIsgandarli do you have any other migrations which use `categories` tables (maybe you're trying to add a column or something)?

Comment: @Alexey Mezenin No, I don't have any table which uses categories table.

Answer (score 3):

For me, this error was occurring because of a **scheduled task** in laravel that involved a database lookup. By commenting out that lookup in `laravel/app/Console/Kernel.php` from my scheduled task, I was able to migrate my database again.

Answer (score 0):

This may happen due to any of the following problems:

- Your database setting are not correct. Please check your database
  settings again.
- The database name is not correct. May be the database your code is
  trying to get tables from is not same as the database you mentioned
  in your database configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. I fixed it, by deleting the database first,
then I imported the previous database manually.

And fortunately at that time I still had the previous database backup.

Maybe if you don't have a previous database backup, You can copy all database migrations to a new laravel project, then run 'php artisan migrate' to get the same database as the previous database,

Answer (score 0):

The problem in my case was that the boot functions in several app/Providers/*Provider.php files were being executed when running

```
php artisan migrate
```

You can comment these out as noted elsewhere but another robust option is to add a conditional

```
public function boot()
{
    if (env('SKIP_BOOTERS')) {
        return;
    }
    

    // Access DB...
}
```

And then run the migration with the env var set

```
SKIP_BOOTERS=true php artisan migrate
```

This allows the code to be checked in and the CI to run with the patched code