# Internal server error on AJAX callback Laravel Dropdown example

Tags: ajax, laravel-5.3

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<center>
    <h1>Laravel Dynamic Drop Down with ajax</h1>

    <span>Product Category: </span>
    <select style="width: 200px" class="productcategory" id="prod_cat_id">

        <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">-Select-</option>
        @foreach($prod as $cat)
            <option value="{{$cat->id}}">{{$cat->product_cat_name}}</option>
        @endforeach

    </select>

    <span>Product Name: </span>
    <select style="width: 200px" class="productname">

        <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Product Name</option>
    </select>

    <span>Product Price: </span>
    <input type="text" class="prod_price">



</center>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(document).on('change','.productcategory',function(){
            // console.log("hmm its change");

            var cat_id=$(this).val();
            // console.log(cat_id);
            var div=$(this).parent();

            var op=" ";

            $.ajax({
                type:'get',
                url:'{!!URL::to('findProductName')!!}',
                data:{'id':cat_id},
                success:function(data){
                    //console.log('success');

                    //console.log(data);

                    //console.log(data.length);
                    op+='<option value="0" selected disabled>chose product</option>';
                    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                    op+='<option value="'+data[i].id+'">'+data[i].productname+'</option>';
                   }

                   div.find('.productname').html(" ");
                   div.find('.productname').append(op);
                },
                error:function(){

                }
            });
        });

        $(document).on('change','.productname',function () {
            var prod_id=$(this).val();

            var a=$(this).parent();
            console.log(prod_id);
            var op="";
            $.ajax({
                type:'get',
                url:'{!!URL::to('findPrice')!!}',
                data:{'id':prod_id},
                dataType:'json',//return data will be json
                success:function(data){
                    console.log("price");
                    console.log(data.price);

                    // here price is coloumn name in products table data.coln name

                    a.find('.prod_price').val(data.price);

                },
                error:function(){

                }
            });


        });

    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
;

when i check it on the console i m getting error as GET http://localhost/dropdown/public/findProductName?id=2 500 (Internal Server Error) 
what is the problem in the code [this is the error page][1]

when i check it on the console i m getting error as GET http://localhost/dropdown/public/findProductName?id=2 500 (Internal Server Error) 
what is the problem in the code [this is the error page][1]
```

when i check it on the console i m getting error as GET http://localhost/dropdown/public/findProductName?id=2 500 (Internal Server Error) 
    what is the problem in the code [this is the error page][1]

```
when i check it on the console i m getting error as GET http://localhost/dropdown/public/findProductName?id=2 500 (Internal Server Error) 
what is the problem in the code [this is the error page][1]

when i check it on the console i m getting error as GET http://localhost/dropdown/public/findProductName?id=2 500 (Internal Server Error) 
what is the problem in the code [this is the error page][1]
```

i have put full code of the page
      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7lMv.png

Comment: Have a look to error logs to have full explained message...

Comment: @MathieuDormeval now i have edited the code and put full code in the page

Comment: @MathieuDormeval  i m using laravel  5.3

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37535315/where-are-logs-located to see where are logs located